# Android httpRequest caching

Tags: android, caching

My application is using HttpRequest for many times. is there a way to not call Rest for every time?

i.e How maintain cache for Api Request call. and it should also be worked when there is no internet

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728

Volley is the answer.

Comment: Thnak you Sergi Castellsagué Millán, Volley is the best answer. Example code is at http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/

Answer (score 3):

Android have own classes to cache responses.
To turn cache you should call [HttpResponseCache.install](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html#install%28java.io.File,%20long%29) method. Such as

```
HttpResponseCache.install(getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024); //10MB cache size
```

and when you open connection call

```
connection.setUseCaches(true);
```

Somthing like this

```
URL url = new URL("http://site.com/");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setUseCaches(true);
```

Also you can read this [topic](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)